# Why does cut return the same value in for loop?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, cut

I am trying to cut text from each individual file using linux centos6. For some reason it keeps returning the same value from the *first* file  and does not return the value from each individual file

For example when I run this following command

```
for d in ~/assets/*/client_custom.css; do  sed -n 73p ~/assets/*/style.css |  cut -c  29-35 ; done
```

If there are 20 directories it will bring back

```
#3a1504
#3a1504
#3a1504
#3a1504
#3a1504
#3a1504
#3a1504
```

...20 times

What I am trying to get back is each individual value from the style.css from all the directories.

Is there anyone that can guide me on how I can get that accomplished and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

But the reason is very simple.  You are operating on a single file from ~/assets/*/style.css expansion.  The rest of them are ignored.  I'm really taking guesses now, but you probably meant something like this:

```
for d in ~/assets/*/style.css; do  sed -n 73p "$d" |  cut -c  29-35 ; done
```

$d is a variable that cotains the filename each iteration.